# How to change an action starting position?

Tags: animation

I have these 2 armatures actions strip in NLA editor:

- action 1 starting from pt A ending at pt B
- action 2 starting from pt C ending at pt D (with multiple LocRotScale on each path ofc) .

So at this pt armature just jump from B to C at the end of action 1 ofc.

How can we make action 2 starting from pt B ? ..and get that action 3 result.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNwTr.png]

Found a dirty workaround so far by adding an empty & parenting the armature on it. Then moving + key frame that empty with some dirty f curves fill in graph editor ^^ Guess there must be a properly way to achieve that goal without having to deal with that extra garbage track. =)

Here's my first ever blender 1mn anim with that "action stich" issues. I wish i could improve the result on the 2nd one i'm "working" on .
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNDjeKfk4sU

EDIT: Screen Captures of the NLA editor

Screen 1: frame 99 / end location of armature Action 1
Screen 2: frame 100 / start location of armature Action 2

Goal : Update Action 2 to start from frame 99 location

[image: End_location_Action_1]
[image]

Comment: Please show a screen capture of Blender with you NLA work.  At this point (not pt) I find your question to be not clear.  What is [ofc] ?  Your textual description may not be a useful as some well selected and considered screen captures.

Comment: I do not find anything particularly wrong wtih a parent empty.  Next time you can plan better.  Or use the candidate answer below.

Comment: Did you create these actions or were they created by someone  else?  This is a question about planning.

Comment: Hey atomic thx for having a look on this beginner stuff . ofc stands for"of course" =) Edited post with screenshots , hope it ll be more clear. Actions are imported from mocap .bvh files from https://sites.google.com/a/cgspeed.com/cgspeed/motion-capture/cmu-bvh-conversion

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the delta transform panel with ...
location to move all keyframes by the same amount for that timespan

[image]